# phpunit test depending on other test that uses dataprovider

Tags: phpunit

I've this situation

```
public class MyTest extends .... {

   function providerA(){
     return array(array("a"));
   }

   function providerB(){
     return array(array("b"));
   }

    /**
   * @dataProvider providerA
   */
   function testOne($a){
      $c = "something";
      return $c;
   }


    /**
    * @depends testOne
    * @dataProvider providerB
    */
   function testTwo($b,$c){
       var_dump($b);
       var_dump($c);
   }

}
```

var_dump($c)  -> is always null, why?
I cannot figure out what is happened. On the pdf of phpunit I found this sentence: 
"When a test depends on a test that uses data providers, the depending test will be executed
when the test it depends upon is successful for at least one data set. The result of a test that
uses data providers cannot be injected into a depending test."

How can achieve my goal or a result that work in the same way?

Comment: I'm unclear about what you're asking. Are you assuming that the return value of one test will be passed to the next one? That contradicts what you say here: "The result of a test that uses data providers cannot be injected into a depending test."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to make a static property, which will be filled with data from the `testOne`. Because of the `@depends` annotation, `testTwo` will not run if `testOne` fails. `testOne` will add value to the static property `c` which will be used in the `testTwo` test.

However, I think better practice is to separate both tests. Thus, the data needed for `testTwo` will all provided by `providerB` (not depended on other test).

```
private static $c = array(array("c"));

function providerA() {
    return array(array("a"));
}

/**
 * @dataProvider providerA
 */
function testOne($a) {
    $c = "something";
    self::$c[0][] = $c;
    $this->assertTrue(true);
}
/**
 * @depends testOne
 */
function testTwo() {
    var_dump(self::$c);
}
```